# Null space isomorphic to range iff closed

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

> Problem 5.3.35 from Folland: Let $\mathscr{X}$ and $\mathscr{Y}$ be Banach spaces, $T\in L(\mathscr{X},\mathscr{Y})$, $\mathscr{N} =\{x: Tx = 0\}$, and $\mathscr{M} = range(T)$. Then $\mathscr{X}/\mathscr{N}(T)$ is isomorphic to $\mathscr{M}$ iff $\mathscr{M}$ is closed.

Normally I would of attempted to prove this but I am pretty lost on where to start, I think my first step should be to show that $T$ is bijective then that would imply $T$ is an isomorphism but I am not sure. Any suggestions is greatly appreciated. I will edit this post if I come up with anything.

Comment: The title asks about the null space being isomorphic but the question has the quotient space $X/\ker T$, I'm assuming you're really interested in the quotient space right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's an application of the open mapping theorem. I'm a bit new to Functional analysis but I think this is the reasoning:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and $T\in L(X,Y)$. Then
$$T(X) \text{ is closed } \iff X/\ker T \cong T(X).$$

(Range of $T$ is denoted as $T(X)$ and kernel of $T$ is the null space of $T$)

Proof:
Suppose $T(X)$ is closed. Define $\phi: X/\ker T \to Y$ as $\phi(x+\ker T)=Tx$. Now $\phi$ is a (well defined) bounded linear bijective mapping from $X/\ker T \to T(X)$ (why?) and since $Y$ is complete, and $T(X)\subset Y$ a closed subspace, we know that $T(X)$ is complete. Thus by the open mapping theorem, $\phi$ is an isomorphism of $X/\ker T \to T(X)$.

Conversely, if $X/\ker T \cong T(X)$ then $T(X)$ is complete since it is isomorphic to $X/\ker T$, which is also a Banach space (why?), hence $T(X)$ is closed.

Comment: I appreciate you trying but this goes way over my head

Comment: Which parts are unfamiliar? I can provided more details, if desired, like any definitions or the lemmas/theorems used, or missing steps.

Comment: The way you defined $\phi$ just does not seem obvious to me, as in I can't see myself being like oh right if I define this then clearly this will work, do you know what I mean?

Comment: Also I don't see how it is a bijective mapping to $Y$

Comment: My apologies, the codomain should have been $T(X)$. Then range of $\phi$ is $T(X)$ (look at the formula) so it's clearly surjective. The injectivity comes from the fact that $\ker \phi=\{0\}$. I didn't come up with the definition of $\phi$ myself, it is a standard mapping used in the theory of quotient spaces. It is the composition of the linear function $T: X\to Y$ and the quotient map $\pi: X\to X/\ker T$ where $\pi(x)=x+\ker T$ and $x+\ker T$ is the set equal to $\{x+a \in X: a\in \ker T\}$, i.e. $\phi=T\circ \pi$.

Comment: Ok, yea I don't know where I could have come up with that myself or even read about it since it is not in the Folland book. When you state that $X/ker T$ is a bijjective mapping does that need to be shown? is that why you asked why

Comment: That's very odd that they'd pose a question about quotient space $X/N(X)$ but not give any mention to concepts related to mappings on quotient spaces... anyway, yes that is why i asked "why", however in my last comment I sketched  the surjectivity and the injectivity (could use more details perhaps?), so bijectivity follows... So the "why" only applies to proving it is bounded, which I can't seem to figure out right now....

Comment: So is your proof complete or no?

Comment: I can add all the missing details except the claim that the function is bounded. I only left them out so i didnt provide a full solution, giving you nothing to do. I saw other instances of this question but they started out w bounded linear mappings or continuous linear mappings so you wouldnt have to prove that property. When im near a computer i can link you to those references if you want.

Comment: Whatever you think will help, I have not come up with anything, still lost on this one. I can ask my prof tomorrow.

Comment: Hey sorry i never had time yesterday. Did your professor clarify anything? Id like to know what they said, as i mentioned im somewhat new to functional analysis as well.

Comment: Unfortunately he cancelled class today, I will find out for sure on Friday, I will let you know